# Get java code to check AP isolation is enabled?

Tags: java, udp

I am building a chat application to communicate locally like IP messenger.
When AP isolation is enabled i get only my IP and gateway.gateway. That's why i can't chat to others.I am not the administrator  of the network. My question how can i check in java that AP isolation is enabled as if i can display a alert message for client?

I have searched many sites.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on this Q&A that explains how AP Isolation is implemented:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16751/wireless-client-isolation-how-does-it-work-and-can-it-be-bypassed

Apparently, all of the work is done in the access point, and it is simply donw by filtering packets.  On the basis of this, the only way that a computer tell if it was isolated would be if it could only "see" itself and the AP on the network.  Even that isn't a reliable indication, because it would also see that if other systems were temporarily "off".

But *could* you test it in Java?

Not in pure Java, AFAIK.  To find out what IP addresses / MAC addresses are active, you need either "raw IP packet" access or access to the ARP tables, or equivalent.  Neither of those are available via pure Java APIs.

Comment: I saw the above link .I need more deep concept.Please help me.

Comment: What more do you need?  Basically, I've said it can't be done in pure Java.  If you are going to implement it at all (in non-pure Java), you will need to understand how IP networking works, and that's beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question.

Comment: Actually i am working this task with a my  network admin colleague .He supports me networking concepts.What do mean about non pure java(Socket programming or other)?.Please give me some java code structure if u have time for me.Thanks.

Comment: 1) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/100percentpurejavacookbook-4-1-1-150165.pdf  2)  I don't have time.  3) Ask your network admin colleague to explain how to do it in some other programming language.  Java is not suitable for this kind of thing.